# How to create an own animation timing function?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

In UIView animation blocks I can specify timing curves like UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut and so on. Is there a way of providing an own timing function to core animation, which behaves different from the defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. UIView animations doesn't expose this setting. But you can use CAAnimation, where you could create a custom bezier curve timing function (CAMediaTimingFunction).

Comment: Which kind of animation would be most sufficient to match the behavior of an default UIView animation block? Something like CABasicAnimation?